# PHP XML (DOM) Extension: installed but not listed in phpinfo in centos

Tags: php, xml, dom, centos

I am trying to install DOM extension in CentOS. Extension Got installed with Dependency with below command and Then I have restarted service.

```
yum install php-xml 
sudo service httpd restart
```

[image]

but when I am looking in `phpinfo()` it is not reflecting and i am getting this runtime error

[image: runtime error for DOM in CentOS]

I have tried some other related answer too but did not get so far.  please let me know if i am missing something here
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tried for the issue. I found out that I have to restart php-fpm where as i was restarting httpd and and other services

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```